# Index orientdb for the shortestpath

Tags: orientdb

I have a CSV document of the vertices of a graph and other document of the edges of the graph, I loaded the documents and I have formed the graph, my question is how I can create an index white the vertices and edges.

I read that with indices the runtime is lower and need to create a function that calculates the shortest path.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You want to create an index on vertexes and edges because the default shortestpath functions is slow in your case? So you want an alternative shortespath function in java and/or javascript? You can create indexes on vertexes, but for edges you can create them only if you have propeties on edge.

Can you explain better your case with examples and/or the schema of your database.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

my file of edges (.csv) have a source, destin and weight for example 1,5,8 and my file of vertex has all vertexes ...... I need to create two indexes (vertexes and edges )because a need to calculate the all pairs shortestpath

[csv files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPRuC.png)